# How to force run loop with specific sequence

Tags: ansible

I'm looking for way to run few tasks (application upgrade) only on one server and copy installation folder to all other servers in the cluster.
I want the playbook will be more generic in case I will add more server into inventory file.

Sample inventory:

```ini
[tabapp_main]
server1

[tabapp_followers]
server2
server3

[tabapp:children]
tabapp_main
tabapp_followers
```

Sample playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: upgrade tab app
  hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: stop tab app on all nodes
    systemd:
      name: tab
      state: stopped

- name: upgrade first node to latest app version
  hosts: tabapp_main
  tasks:
    shell: wget www /tmp
    shell: rpm uvh -d /opt/tab

- name: copy upgraded installation folders from server1 to other 2 servers.
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    shell: "cp {{ groups.tabapp_main[0] }}/opt/tab {{ tabapp_followers[0]/opt }}"  
    shell: "cp {{ groups.tabapp_main[0] }}/opt/tab {{ tabapp_followers[1]/opt }}"
```

I'm using AWX to run playbooks, I created tabapp_main and tabapp_followers groups, based on slice method will it work? any other idea?

Comment: do you need that a specific host execute the command? if it is acceptable that any host executes it, you can use `run_once`.

why are you using `shell: cp` and not the [copy module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html)

Comment: `based on slice method will it work?` <= do you really think that asking on SO if a piece of code will work will be faster than trying it yourself? Just do it and edit your question with a [mre] showing the exact problem you have (if you still have one....).

Answer (score 1):

Use inventory plugin *constructed*. See

```bash
shell> ansible-doc -t inventory constructed
```

For example, create the tree

```bash
shell> tree inventory/
inventory/
├── 01-hosts
└── 02-constructed.yml

0 directories, 2 files
```

In the hosts file assign the master and the slaves

```ini
shell> cat inventory/01-hosts 
server1 ansible_host=10.1.0.61
server2 ansible_host=10.1.0.62
server3 ansible_host=10.1.0.63

[tabapp]
server1 tab_app=master
server2 tab_app=slave
server3 tab_app=slave

[tabapp:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_user=admin
ansible_become=yes
ansible_become_user=root
ansible_become_method=sudo
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python3.8
```

Then, the plugin will create groups *upgrade_tab_app* and *copy_tab_app*

```yaml
shell> cat inventory/02-constructed.yml 
plugin: constructed
groups:
  upgrade_tab_app: tab_app == 'master'
  copy_tab_app: tab_app == 'slave'
```

---

Test the inventory

```yaml
shell> ansible-inventory -i inventory --list --yaml
all:
  children:
    copy_tab_app:
      hosts:
        server2:
          ansible_become: 'yes'
          ansible_become_method: sudo
          ansible_become_user: root
          ansible_connection: ssh
          ansible_host: 10.1.0.62
          ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/local/bin/python3.8
          ansible_user: admin
          tab_app: slave
        server3:
          ansible_become: 'yes'
          ansible_become_method: sudo
          ansible_become_user: root
          ansible_connection: ssh
          ansible_host: 10.1.0.63
          ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/local/bin/python3.8
          ansible_user: admin
          tab_app: slave
    tabapp:
      hosts:
        server1:
          ansible_become: 'yes'
          ansible_become_method: sudo
          ansible_become_user: root
          ansible_connection: ssh
          ansible_host: 10.1.0.61
          ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/local/bin/python3.8
          ansible_user: admin
          tab_app: master
        server2: {}
        server3: {}
    ungrouped: {}
    upgrade_tab_app:
      hosts:
        server1: {}
```

---

Create the playbook for testing

```yaml
- name: Stop tab app
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |
          systemd:
            name: tab
            state: stopped

- name: Upgrade tab app on master
  hosts: upgrade_tab_app
  vars:
    fetched_files: /tmp/tab_upgrade
  tasks:
    - command: mkdir -p /opt/tab
    - command: touch /opt/tab/upgrade
    - fetch:
        src: /opt/tab/upgrade
        dest: "{{ fetched_files }}"

- name: Copy folders from master to slaves
  hosts: copy_tab_app
  vars:
    fetched_files: /tmp/tab_upgrade
    master: "{{ groups.upgrade_tab_app|first }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |
          copy:
            src: {{ fetched_files }}/{{ master }}/opt/tab
            dest: /opt/tab
```

The first play will stop the service on all hosts. The second play will create the upgrade

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_11 ls -la /opt/tab/
total 2
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  3 Dec 11 22:42 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  3 Dec 11 22:42 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  0 Dec 11 22:42 upgrade
```

and the upgrade will will be fetched to */tmp/tab_upgrade* on the localhost

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/tab_upgrade/
/tmp/tab_upgrade/
└── server1
    └── opt
        └── tab
            └── upgrade
```

---

The third play will copy the upgrade folder to the slaves

```yaml
PLAY [Copy folders from master to slaves] ****************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [server2] => 
  msg: |-
    copy:
      src: /tmp/tab_upgrade/server1/opt/tab
      dest: /opt/tab
ok: [server3] => 
  msg: |-
    copy:
      src: /tmp/tab_upgrade/server1/opt/tab
      dest: /opt/tab
```

The playbook is generic. You can add more servers to the inventory file. All masters will be upgraded and the upgrade from the first *master* will be copied to all slaves.

---

**Notes**

The module [*fetch*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fetch_module.html#parameter-src) will fetch a single file only. Use the module [*find*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html) if there are more files. See below the example of the second play for testing

```yaml
- name: Upgrade tab app on master
  hosts: upgrade_tab_app
  vars:
    fetched_files: /tmp/tab_upgrade
  tasks:
    - command: mkdir -p /opt/tab
    - command: touch /opt/tab/upgrade1
    - command: touch /opt/tab/upgrade2
    - find:
        path: /opt/tab
      register: tab_upgrade
    - fetch:
        src: "{{ item }}"
        dest: "{{ fetched_files }}"
      loop: "{{ tab_upgrade.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
```

This will fetch all files from the directory */opt/tab* to the localhost

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/tab_upgrade/
/tmp/tab_upgrade/
└── server1
    └── opt
        └── tab
            ├── upgrade1
            └── upgrade2

3 directories, 2 files
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities (non exhaustive list). My preferred is the last.

### Use list index/slice

*Note: order of servers in groups is not always reliable during execution so that one is fast but not preferred on the long run.*

Example pseudo playbook

```yaml
---
- name: Tasks to run on all tabapp nodes
  hosts: tabapp
  tasks:
    # ...

- name: Tasks to run on first tabapp node
  hosts: "{{ groups.tabapp[0] }}"
  tasks:
    # ...

- name: Tasks to run on remaining tabapp nodes
  hosts: "{{ groups.tabapp[1:] }}"
  tasks:
    # ...
```

### Use the main server name (hardcoded)

*Note: to dig into the syntax to use in `hosts:` see [Ansible patterns](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_patterns.html)*

```yaml
---
- name: Tasks to run on all tabapp nodes
  hosts: tabapp
  tasks:
    # ...

- name: Tasks to run on server1
  hosts: server1
  tasks:
    # ...

- name: Tasks to run on all nodes except server1
  hosts: tabapp:!server1
  tasks:
    # ...
```

### Use subgroups

This is my preferred option because it is the most flexible, scalable and self documented.

It requires to modify (slightly...) your inventory to something like:

```ini
# Keep this one with a single server. It's more an alias than a group.
[tabapp_main]
server1

[tabapp_followers]
server2
server3

[tabapp:children]
tabapp_main
tabapp_followers
```

And the corresponding pseudo playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Tasks to run on all tabapp nodes
  hosts: tabapp
  tasks:
    # ...

- name: Tasks to run on tabapp main node
  hosts: tabapp_main
  tasks:
    # ...

- name: Tasks to run on tabapp followers nodes
  hosts: tabapp_followers
  tasks:
    # ...
```